# New users created in Oracle 11 need 'grant use on edition ora$base to new-user;'

Tags: sql, oracle

This occurs in a database copied from another server. For all new user I must execute the next code, otherwise I get error ORA-38802:

`grant use on edition ora$base to <new-user>;`

Is it possible for new users to get that privilege automatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle account model does not work in the way you describe. The user which creates a user has no special privileges over the objects which that user creates. All users are born in a state of manumission

There are only two levels of object privilege:

- privileges granted on specific objects in individual schemas
- privileges granted on all objects of a given type in every schema,
  gained through the ANY privilege.

The first level is the mechanism you mention by which SLAVE grants rights on its objects to MASTER. The second level is extremely powerful because it applies across all the objects owned by all users, including the Oracle DBMS accounts such as SYS. Consequently it is normal for only DBA users to have the ANY level privileges.

The reason for this state of affairs is that Oracle employs users and schemas as the mechanism for controlling access to data and functionality. A user which is wholly owned by another user doesn't make any sense in that context.

The best way i see regarding to your question two ways

- Proxy User
- Database Vault

Comment: Actually, the problem is that I assign that privilege to sysman but emca fails with error ORA-38802. I run 'emca -config dbcontrol db -repos recreate' and in the log file I can see that error on sysman user. 
It seems that the process resets the privileges of sysman.

Comment: What version you are using ? 11g

Comment: Solved.
Servers was not in the same level patches.
I copied datafiles from a server in Oracle 11.2.0.4.14 and target server was 11.2.0.4.0